# aws datapipeline - psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out

Tags: amazon-redshift, subnet, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying to load data from redshift to dynamodb via Data Pipeline shellcommand activity using python script. 
The hostname and port details are hardcoded in the script. 
Issue arises when I try to run the Datapipeline job. I receive the below error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
Is the server running on host "1*.***.**.*" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5***?
```

I understand the redshift is not accessible to ec2 instance and hence this issue. So I passed the subnet Id and security groups created for redshift cluster as parameters to EC2 instance to be created. But now I see my shellcommand activity "waiting_for_runner" state,despite the ec2 instance is active and running.

Anyone has faced similar issues and resolved ?
Any suggestions would be appreciated !

Comment: Resolved the issue.

Comment: Resolved the issue. The subnet Id's didn't have IPV4 CIDR of the redshift cluster maintained in inbound rule.